# Nuget dependency seems to be overriden for lower version SOMEHOW

Tags: .net, .net-core, dependencies, versioning, nuget-package

I have a strange issue with Nuget dependencies. I have a project as nuget package, that targets another project also as nuget package. Even when everything says version 1.2.3 it turns into 1.2.2.2.

I made probably mistake to switch between 3 and 4 numbered versions:

```
1.2.3
1.2.2.2
1.2.2.1
1.2.2
1.2.0
1.1.9
```

It behaves as if the dependency on 1.2.3 would not be recognized as 1.2.3 but 1.2.3.0 which would not be found(?) and then next lower is 1.2.2.2.

But brace yourself, I thought that OK, there is an issue with 3/4 version format, so I turned to 4 numbered format and pushed two more versions after 1.2.3:

```
1.2.5.1
1.2.4.1
1.2.3
```

When I made version 1.2.4.1 it all started to work well, 1.2.4.1 as required by the project was also acquired and built with 1.2.4.1.

But it all went crazy when I pushed version 1.2.5.1, the project was updated to acquire 1.2.5.1, it is installed yet during the build it is overridden for some reason to target 1.2.4.1 and I really have no clue now why?

After build in file xxx.deps.json is this override:

```
"GreenSuperGreen.Benchmarking.NetStandard/1.2.5.1": {
"dependencies": {
"Concurrent.FastReflection.NetStandard": "1.0.1",
"GreenSuperGreen.NetStandard": "1.2.5.1",
"System.Collections.Immutable": "1.5.0"
},
"runtime": {
"lib/netstandard2.0/GreenSuperGreen.Benchmarking.NetStandard.dll": {
"assemblyVersion": "1.2.4.1",
"fileVersion": "1.2.4.1"
}
}
},
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/package-versioning#version-basics

Comment: I have not found in documentation anything, that would explain version override.

Comment: Of you actual read it, you should see the four parts version numbers should not be used any more.

Comment: The document uses examples of four number version as well. The document does not imply that there will be only three numbers versions allowed and four numbers prohibited, new nuget versions will have to handle backwards compatibility for quite some time. Also version normalization and 3 vs 4 number format does not explain the issues. It seems that it happens elsewhere in build process, versions are not normalized but clearly overridden.

Comment: Please do not imply that I am lazy or liar without any evidence. Thanks...

Comment: I have no interest in asserting your are lazy or not, but if you insist using something (four parts version numbers in this case) that rarely people care about, you should be aware of the risks of hitting bugs. BTW, "will have to handle backwards compatibility"? Microsoft may or may not be able to guarantee that, but they do take bug reports, https://github.com/nuget/home/issues

Comment: The assertion was made by: "Of you actual read it". Now, nuget.org has many active packages with four number versions and some actually owned by Microsoft like few xamarin packages with recent updates in recent days or weeks. Reasonable backward compatibility is necessary or nuget.org would have to be reformatted with new version format. Also look on tooling in VisualStudio, new csproj settings of NetStandard and NetCore projects that have 4 text boxes to describe version. Also please read the SemVer 2.0.0 it is actually supporting four-part versions: https://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, but not the explanation.

If the project, that depends on the nuget package either DotNet or DotNetCore has set in project file:

```
  <PreserveCompilationContext>false</PreserveCompilationContext>
```

Then version dependency starts working correctly again.